# Trying to do ng generate component in my cli but it is saying Unable to find any apps in `.angular-cli.json`

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am working with angular 4, firebase and ionic 3 for my app. I am trying to ng generate component login in my command line but it says Unable to find any apps in `.angular-cli.json`. I have a package.json in my folder, but how do i add .angular-cli.json.  This is what I have in my folder. Do you think it is because I am using ionic serve and not ng serve?

[image]

Comment: nevermind, I guess I can put my components in manually

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Ionic Cli`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/) which you would have installed using `npm i -g ionic`

It does not have angular-cli.json to use angular cli on the project

To generate page do:

```
ionic g page login
```

For a component:

```
ionic g component login
```

See full list [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/generate/)